# How do I get the dirname of the calling method when it is in a different file in nodejs?

Tags: node.js

Let's say I have two files, `dir/a.js` and `lib/b.js`

a.js:

```
b = require('../lib/b');
b.someFn();
```

b.js:

```
var fallback = "./config.json";
module.exports = {
  someFn = function(jsonFile) {
    console.log(require(jsonFile || fallback);
  }
}
```

The entire purpose of `b.js` in this example is to read a json file, so I might call it as `b.someFn("path/to/file.json")`.

But I want there to be a default, like a config file. But the default should be relative to **a.js** and not **b.js**. In other words, I should be able to call `b.someFn()` from `a.js`, and it should say, "since you didn't pass me the path, I will assume a default path of `config.json`." But the default should be relative to `a.js`, i.e. should be `dir/config.json` and **not** `lib/config.json`, which I would get if I did `require(jsonFile)`.

I could get the `cwd`, but that will only work if I launch the script from within `dir/`.

Is there any way for `b.js` to say, inside `someFn()`, "give me the `__dirname` of the function that called me?"

Comment: Can you modify the `b` module?

Comment: Yes, I own `b`, no problem. Actually, `b` is turning into a module, I just want it to be able to have a default file relative to the caller.

Comment: Then simply set use the directory where a.js is located. See the answer.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Use [callsite](http://npmjs.org/package/callsite), then:

b.js:

```
var path = require('path'),
    callsite = require('callsite');

module.exports = {
  someFn: function () {
    var stack = callsite(),
        requester = stack[1].getFileName();

    console.log(path.dirname(requester));
  }
};
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, using [`parent-module`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/parent-module):

```
const path = require('path');
const parentModule = require('parent-module');

// get caller of current script
console.log(path.dirname(parentModule()));
// get caller of module, change './index.js' to your "main" script
console.log(path.dirname(parentModule(require.resolve('./index.js'))));
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to get the directory of the script of the caller function, then use the stacktrace as the above answer shows, otherwise, what's the problem of hardcoding the directory of a.js?

```
var fallback = "dir_a/config.json";
module.exports = {
  someFn = function(jsonFile) {
    console.log(require(jsonFile || fallback);
  }
}
```

Comment: Because `b.js` doesn't know about the directory of `a.js`. In my example, I simplified it so that we know both, but really `b.js` is inside an `npm` module.